# Whats happens after death?

Tags: death

When a human being dies, their body dissolves into other bodies, i.e., other humans, plants, air, water, rocks, sand, etc. But what really happens to our

1. Consciousness
2. memory
3. thoughts
4. intelligence &
5. Karma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts, memory, intelligence and karma continue to live on in the world after you, in some form or the other.

People still remember the Buddha, Mahatma Gandhi, Martin Luther King, Albert Einstein, Richard Feynman and other famous people in history and still read their writings or listen to to their speeches or admire their statues or portraits, or be inspired by their stories.

After you are gone, your family members, friends and acquaintances continue to remember what you taught them or impressed upon them.

It is for this reason that the Buddha praised the setting up of the stupas of the Buddha, arahats, wheel-turning monarchs and other such great people, in the Mahaparinibbana Sutta, as memorials to continue inspiring the people.

Answer (score 4):

If good householder wouldn't not have desire for another becoming and certain inclination,, he wouldn't have come here, or? So after dying off elsewhere, lack of satisfaction, breaking apart there, desire for not-becoming, he became another time, in this realm, not sure of what he will meet, but dying of another time here is for sure. But if he gains awakening here, understanding the way it is, arises, decays, he will no more take birth, no more ignorance, not-knowing, no more craving for becoming anywhere another time.

Birth is taken, where ever possible and fit for once inclination, if not having gained full awakening, good householder. Bhava (becoming)-mind arises for beings after the break up of the Body. Why? Because of [Tanha](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca2/tanha_en.html) (thirst, craving) based on not-knowing, ignorance, [Avija](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca2/avijja_en.html). The sequence in detail, of the [wheel of wandering](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca1/samsara_en.html), on is given generously by the Sublime Buddha in the [secound Noble Truth](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca2/index_en.html). What ever takes Birth is subject to [decay, suffering](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca1/index_en.html).

May good householder had a good blessed, even last birth, here.

Some words might be of additional support for understanding: [Why beings take birth, even in most worse existences and circumstances?](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=8634.msg14830#msg14830)

*[Note that this isn't given for wandering on, stacks, exchange, trades for it, but for release from this wheel]*

Answer (score 2):

> When a human being dies, his body dissolves into other bodies, i.e
> other humans, plants, air, water, rocks, sand etc. But what really
> happens to our    1   Consciousness   2   memory  3   thoughts    4   intelligence
> &     5   Karma.

Consciousness is impermanent... It arises , is subject to changes and can vanish ...
Memory is impermanent too... thoughts are impermanent... intelligence is impermanent... karma is impermanent... it arises , is subject to change and can vanish .... I am none of those ... none of those belong to me ... none of those is myself ...
(Form or body is also impermanent)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some understanding of Dependent Origination may some help.

ie:- Vinnana Paccaya Namarupa

- Namarupa Paccaya Vinnana

In other words, even if your body is dissolved your vinnana (re-birth making consciousness or Patisandi Vinnana) is still there to create another body (Nama-rupa).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one can think about it;

- What was before our being percepient in dependence on the physical body is unknown to us. (What haøpened before birth)
- What will be after the breakup of the body in dependence on which we are percepient is unknown to us (what will happen after death)

Both unknowns are semantically equal.

What we know is that after an unknown percipience came to be. So we know that the unknown sometimes preceed percipience.

Therefore it is reasonable to assume that it will happen again but in another body.

We don't here know the cause for the arising of our percipience but we assume that it will likely come into play again.